# Render a ASP.NET control in the master page code-behind

Tags: asp.net, caching, substitution

I'm using a Substitution control in my master page, and I want to render a user control content (related to the login area of my website) in the Substitution .
Seems like I must have a reference for the requested page so that it could render the control. But I need to render the control in the master page itself, as it's shared across multiple pages in my website. What are the guidelines to achieve that?

Tks

Comment: I was able to load the User Control, but ASP.NET is complaining that the information for state are invalid or corrupted.

I loaded the user control this way:

        Page pageHolder = new Page();
        UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl("MyControl.ascx");
        pageHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);
        StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);
        return output.ToString();

Comment: Won't pageHolder get rendered automatically when the page is served up?  I'm not sure why you render it yourself first.  Also, if you have form controls in your user control but don't have a `<form>` around it as well, it will complain about the invalid state.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to render a user control from your MasterPage code-behind, and add it to a Substitution that's also in the master page?  Why do you need a reference to the page that's using the master?

Assuming your using VB and that I understand your question, try this in your MasterPage code-behind:

```
Dim someControl As MyControl = CType((New Page()).LoadControl("~/Path/To/MyControl.ascx"), MyControl)
mySubstitution.Controls.Add(someControl)
```

Comment: The Substitution control that I'm referring is the  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.substitution.aspx, used for output cached pages. (: